# Gmail automatic logout due to multiple logins during one session

Tags: gmail

My suspicion is with my Gmail account, I fear it has been hacked because I was logged in and randomly received a pop-up notification stating a second login has been detected from the same session.  This struck me as odd because in the list of IP addresses in Gmail's recent activity, only my IP is listed and the only other device that has my username/password stored is my smartphone which auto syncs with my account but it was turned off at the time.

Has anyone ever seen this before, and are there any preventative measures I can take to better secure my account with Google?

Comment: Perhaps try *changing your password*? Of course, I have to warn you, Google has a stupid policy where you cannot use any of your previous passwords... ever... again...

Comment: Have you examined http://googlesystem.blogspot.se/2008/07/find-who-has-access-to-your-gmail.html to give you an indication if it could be some of your devices (I'm thinking google notifier or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this, but I strongly recommend [adding 2-factor authentication to your Gmail account](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744) to make it more secure.

It will add a second "password" used to approve new devices you login with, via a phone call or text message.